# ng build throws Cannot read property 'startTag' of null exception

Tags: angular, angular8, ng-build

I want to publish my Angular 8 app to IIS. Then I've started to follow the deployment instructions.
When I build my project on prod mode with base-href, operation throws an error. If I build in development mode(just ng build), there is no error but I have to build in production mode.
--base-href causes the error. What can I do now?

Here is error:

> Cannot read property 'startTag' of null
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'startTag' of null
>       at Object.augmentIndexHtml (D:\ReklamUssuProjects\DevBranch\RULink\RULink.UI\Angular\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\utilities\index-file\augment-index-html.js:126:55)
>       at compiler.hooks.emit.tapPromise (D:\ReklamUssuProjects\DevBranch\RULink\RULink.UI\Angular\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\index-html-webpack-plugin.js:70:60)

[image]

Comment: Have you opened an issue on `@angular/cli` repo: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues? It seems something they should have a look.

Comment: Also... you have one permission warning message... if it's possible, try to run the build process as an admin (or just close your editor - it may be just an access conflict)

Comment: @jpavel it's already an admin process :|. I didn't opened but I will.

Answer (score 1):

When I asked to github angular cli issues, problem was solved. Thank you again.

[Github Link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15503#issuecomment-527109454)